# Select a registros que no contengan valor en tabla

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Tengo la siguiente tabla

```
Pedimento | Partida | Identificador | Valor Agregado
6000001 | 1 | TL | 10
6000001 | 1 | PT | 10
6000002 | 1 | TL | 0
6000002 | 2 | XP | 0
6000003 | 3 | PT | 10
6000003 | 4 | TL | 10
```

Como puedo realizar una consulta que me regrese todos los registros que contengan el identificador PT y aquellos que en el campo Valor agregado sea mayor a 0 y no contengan el identificador PT

Nota: Pedimento - Partida serian nuestra agrupacion

El resultado deberia ser algo asi

```
Pedimento | Partida | Identificador | Valor Agregado
6000001 | 1 | PT | 10
6000003 | 3 | PT | 10
6000003 | 4 | TL | 10
```

Edicion: Estaba mal el valor agregado en el primer registro, era 10 en lugar de 0, el problema con el query de filtrar los que tengan valor agregado mayor a 0 es que me traera grupos (pedimento - partida) duplicados (Por ejemplo el pedimento 6000001 partida 1 se duplicara porque uno de sus registros no tiene identificador PT), lo que necesito que me regrese son grupos pedimento - partida que no tengan identificador pt en ninguno de los renglones

Comment: Hola Javier, pregunta, ¿con la modificación que hiciste a tu pregunta, la consulta te debería de traer 4 renglones entonces, no? Dado que el `Pedimento = 6000001` cumple con la condición de que no es `PT` y su `ValorAgregag` es mayor a cero

Comment: El resultado no cambia, el punto es que cada grupo de pedimento - partida tienen sus propios identificadores,

Comment: Me temo que sí cambia el resultado, partiendo del hecho que la consulta traerá `aquellos que contengan PT y aquellos que en el campo Valor agregado sea mayor a 0 y no contengan el identificador PT`, si revisamos para el `Pedimento = 6000001` ambos registros caen en esas condiciones. En cambio, si el resultado que esperas no es este, se deberían plantear las condiciones con mayor exactitud. De hecho, la primer consulta que expone @Gepser en su respuesta, solucionaría tu pregunta.

Comment: Si, pero las condiciones son por pedimento, partida.

Comment: Creo que leí la pregunta tres veces, y todavía no logro entenderla bien. No logro concordar que por un lado quieres los registros que tengan el identificador PT, pero mas abajo dices **.necesito que me regrese son grupos pedimento - partida que no tengan identificador pt en ninguno de los renglones. La cosa está confusa.

Comment: Ahora me pasó lo mismo que a sstan. Pensé que estaba claro, pero ahora con tu edición, el planteo es totalmente contradictorio.

Comment: Digamos que Pedimento - Partida es nuestra clave primaria (Supongamos que los concatenamos y utilizamos ese valor como llave primaria), ahora necesito que regrese todos los registros donde esa llave contenga el identificador PT y aquellos que no lo contenga pero su valoe agregado sea mayor a 0, NO necesito especificamente la informacion del renglon (Sino que llave(s) (concatenacion del pedimento - partida) cumplen las condiciones

Answer (score 0):

Tu consulta, traducida de manera literal quedaría algo así:

```
select * from TABLA 
where (identificador = 'PT') 
   or (identificador != 'PT' and Valor_Agregado > 0) 
group by pedimento, partida, identificador, valor_agregado
```

Ahora el segundo `where` tiene una parte redundante como menciona @Mariano, ya que se devuelven todos los valores que contengan `PT`de todos modos. Optimizándola quedaría así:

```
select * from TABLA 
where (identificador = 'PT') 
   or (Valor_Agregado > 0) 
group by pedimento, partida, identificador, valor_agregado
```

El punto clave es que debes hacer un `OR` en el `where`para que este sea condicional.

Y tal como menciona @mariano, aunque quieras agrupar sólo por dos campos igual debes de ponerlos todos, sólo cuidando de poner al principio los dos campos que te interesan.

Tomando tu ejemplo, el resultado de la consulta sería así:

```
Pedimento | Partida | Identificador | Valor Agregado
6000001 | 1 | PT | 10
6000003 | 3 | PT | 10
6000003 | 4 | TL | 10
```

Comment: En este caso no haría falta la condición `identificador != 'PT'`, y supongo que se deberían agregar los campos no incluidos en el `group by`

Comment: @Mariano lo segundo sí, tienes razón (ya lo agregué a la respuesta), ahora con lo primero creo que no aplica porque la pregunta dice en la segunda condicional `y aquellos que en el campo Valor agregado sea mayor a 0 y no contengan el identificador PT`

Comment: entiendo, pero como también se devuelven todos los `PT`, sería redundante... En cuanto a *agregar campos*, me refería a devolver los suma de `Valor_Agregado`, aunque no lo específico el autor

Comment: @Mariano tienes razón, voy a editarla. Buen ojo para ver eso el que tienes.

Comment: @Gapser habia un error en el primer renglon en el valor agregado, ya habia intentado realizarlo como mencionas pero me repite los grupos de pedimento - partida, creo que no formule correctamente la pregunta, agrege una explicacion a la publicacion